# WebService: How to accept text/xml instead of application/soap+xml

Tags: .net, web-services

I am trying to consume 3rd party webservice and has an error:

System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: The content type **text/xml**; charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (**application/soap+xml**; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly.

Message itself looks correct (first 1024 bytes):

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <soap:Header/>
    <soap:Body> <m:PullActionsResponse xmlns:m="http://172.17.2.8/Test/Actions">
    <m:return xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:type="m:ArrayOfActions">
        <m:Actions>
            <m:Id>51603d29-8469-11e1-8069-bc305bd4fe84</m:Id>
            <m:Name>Discount 20%</m:Name>
            </m:Actions>
...
```

I found msdn article 'Custom Message Encoder: Custom Text Encoder' in MSDN but it doesn't clear how to implement CustomTextMessageBindingElement.

Comment: That error message usually occurs when the web service returns an error as html. How did you get the message you show above. Did you look at the message being returned using a sniffer? What happens when you try to open the web service in a web browser?

Comment: @KevinJunghans - This data is displayed in error message as first 1024 bytes of response.

Comment: Provide the complete response including the error message in your question and you may get an answer that will help.

Comment: Sounds like you are using WCF? What are the configuration settings for the binding?